# Custom font in code behind - Windows Store Apps

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps, custom-font

I have an issue with setting custom font from code behind in Windows Store Apps (**Windows 8.1, C#**).

It is working in `XAML`, but not in code behind. I have added my font *.ttf file to Assets. Set `Build Action` = Content. I have set path to my font file like this:

```
<TextBlock Text="&#xe1de;" FontFamily="ms-appx:///Assets/My-icons.ttf#My-icons"/>
```

It's working (displaying my icon), when I set text property in `XAML`, but as soon as I set text to this `TextBlock` in code behind or create new `TextBlock` with the same properties **in code behind - it's not working** (displaying unicode).

Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this help:

```
char ch = (char)0xF8FF;
YourTextBlock.Text = ch.ToString();
```